# mpdf - Page numbering

Tags: php, mpdf

I am dynamically creating pdf using mpdf. I want to skip cover page from page numbering. I am adding my code below

```
$mpdf->AddPageByArray(
array('resetpagenum' => '1',
'pagenumstyle' => '1',
'suppress' => 'off'));
$mpdf->setFooter("{PAGENO}");
```

Here the page number will be shown from the first page, which is my cover page. I don't want to create blank page between cover page and content pages.

Comment: follow this link https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html#example-2

Comment: I have already gone through this. If I set "'suppress' => 'on')" the page number wont show. After this i want to create a new page again to change the argument values. But this will create a blank page between Cover page and content. I want to avoid that blank page also.